# How do connections and relaying work in MCSessions?

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity, mcsession

The [Multipeer Connectivity Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/) documentation is a bit lacking. Below I have several questions about connections and relaying.

In order to make things easier, I created an image for each question. The legend is as follows:

[image]

For each of the questions, keep these in mind:

- If I disable bluetooth, does the answer change?
- If I disable wi-fi, does the answer change?
- If I disconnect from the same wi-fi network, does the answer change?

---

#### 1. If you connect to one peer, do you get connected to every other peer?

Assume 1 and 2 were connected to a session.

If 1 and 3 connect, do 2 and 3 get connected?

[image]

---

#### 2. What if you already had your own session with peers?

Assume 1 and 2 were connected to a session, and 3 and 4 were connected to a *different* session.

If 1 and 3 connect, do all peers get connected to each other? (e.g. do 2 and 4 get connected?)

[image]

---

#### 3. What happens if two connected devices are no longer in range?

Assume 1, 2, and 3 are all connected and in range of each other.

If 3 moves out of range of 1 (but still in range of 2), do 1 and 3 get disconnected?

Note: For this question assume that they are using device to device communication, not a centralized wi-fi.

**3b. If not, does this mean that every message that 1 sends to 3 get relayed through 2, or will 3 simply not get any messages?**

[image]

---

#### 4. What if the connection is initiated and some devices aren't in range of each other?

Assume 1 and 2 are in range of each other, 2 and 3 are in range of each other, but 1 and 3 are out of range of each other. Assume 1 and 2 are connected to a session, but 3 is not.

If 3 connects to 2, will it get connected to 1 as well?

[image]

---

#### 5. Are advertisements relayed through peers as well?

Again, 1 and 2 are in range, 2 and 3 are in range, but 1 and 3 are out of range.

If 1 advertises its services, will 3 see it (e.g. by it relaying through peer 2)?

**5b. If 2 was also advertising, would this change the answer to the above question? I.e. will 3 see 1's advertisement?**

[image]

---

#### 6. What about browsers, are they ever relayed through peers?

Again, 1 and 2 are in range, 2 and 3 are in range, but 1 and 3 are out of range.

If 3 advertises its services, will 1 see it (e.g. by it relaying through peer 2)?

**6b. If 2 was also browsing, would this change the answer to the above question? I.e. will 1 see 3's advertisement?**

[image]

Comment: Hi, do you have answers for these questions? I am working on an application based on MCP but I find it very unreliable with continuous disconnections :(

Comment: Did you ever found answers to these excellent questions? I am considering using multipeer connectivity, and checking whether the technology is suited for my purposes.

Comment: I am interested in the answers, as well.